# How to React controllable/default-uncontrollable scroll pos

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs

Is there any way to create a react component having *controllable* and/or *default-uncontrollable* **scrolling pos**?

I created a react component having `overflow=scroll/auto`.
Everything is done using `ref=elmRef` trick and manipulating through `useEffect`.
Is it able **not to use** `ref` anyway? I want to make a purely *react way*.

I feel using `ref` is like a `jquery way`. The manipulation is done after actual dom component rendered, and **might trigger** the ***second render*** at startup if the manipulation causing to modify any states. There is a state that the value depend on the scroll position. Rendering dom twice is wasteful performance.

Here the visualization of the component i created:
[image]

Comment: What exactly are you doing with the  `ref`?

Comment: it reads the element.scrollTop and calculates which the section is visible, then set the setActiveIndex(visibleSectionIndex), then getActiveIndex determines the ul>li to highlight

Comment: TBH sounds like a good reason to use `ref`

Comment: i'm looking for a solution similar to scrollPos={scllPos} & scrollPosChanged={handleIt}, so the {ref} can be eliminated & going back to standard react way.

Comment: You would probably need a react onscroll handler and to save the value from it you're going to need a `ref`. It's a matter of weather ref points to a DOM element of a value

Comment: it sound great. but still not purely playing with virtual dom. Not the perfect solution but might the best.